# chart.js doughnut legend in the chart

Tags: chart.js

I am working with chart.js with the doughnut chart.

I want to now if I can show the values of the charts inside the chart.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQM2y.png)

this is my code:

```
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('grafic_assistencia'), {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data :{
                    labels:['OK','NO OK'],  
                    datasets: [{
                      backgroundColor:['#5cb85c','#ff0000'],
                      data:[75,25],
                      datalabels: {
                        anchor: 'end'
                      }
                    }],
                    
                },
                options: {
                    plugins: {
                      datalabels: {
                        backgroundColor: function(context) {
                          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                        },
                        borderColor: 'white',
                        borderRadius: 25,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        color: 'white',
                        display: function(context) {
                          var dataset = context.dataset;
                          var count = dataset.data.length;
                          var value = dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                          return value > count * 1.5;
                        },
                        font: {
                          weight: 'bold'
                        },
                        padding: 6,
                        formatter: Math.round
                      }
                    },
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the datalabels plugin for that
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't working

Comment: Its an interactive axemple that its working so you must be doing something wrong if its not working for you

Comment: I add the script chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min to my html but it is not working, Do you see something strange in my code above? Thanks

Comment: I got the solution, thanks!